# Need to write a set of linear equations for following condition:

Tags: matlab, binary, linear-algebra, linear-programming, gams-math

I have three variables : A, B, C.

I want to write a set of linear equations such that

X = 1 if atleast 2 of A,B,C are ones.

X= 0 if only one of A,B,C is one.

X = 0 if all of them are zero.

A,B and C are binary (0,1).

Kindly suggest a linear equation for this.

Thank you.

Comment: How could you possibly have a linear equation with those non-linear properties?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
X >= A + B - 1
X >= B + C - 1
X >= A + C - 1

X <= A + B
X <= B + C
X <= A + C
```

as mentioned in comment, you didn't define outcome for A=B=C=0, but in that case X -> 0 by inspection.

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your answer by adding one more condition as X>=0; As I have edited my problem again as X = 0 for A=B=C=0. With this addition , I am getting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To implement

```
  A+B+C ≥ 2 => X=1
  A+B+C ≤ 1 => X=0
```

we can write simply:

```
  2X ≤ A+B+C ≤ 2X+1
  A,B,C,X ∈ {0,1}
```

In practice, you may have to formulate the sandwich equation as two inequalities.